# Search text in another text

Tags: iphone

I use below code for check that searchText exist in name or not but this code is case sensitive means if searchText:"Home" and name :"home and " the result is that searchText doesn't exist in name

how can i remove case sensitive?

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText]; 
if(r.location != NSNotFound)
     //searchText exist in name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `rangeOfString:options:` instead, and for the options parameter use `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch`

See the NSString Class Reference about the above method for more info.